# Shiny-server with HighCharts showOuput not found

Tags: highcharts, rcharts, shiny-server

I've developped a shiny application.
It works fine localy (runApp)but not with Shiny-server.
I've got this error message :

Error : Function "showOutput" not found.

like Rcharts package was not found...but it's already installed.

```
> > sessionInfo() R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
> 
> locale:  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=C         LC_TIME=C      
> LC_COLLATE=C         LC_MONETARY=C        LC_MESSAGES=C       
> LC_PAPER=C           LC_NAME=C             [9] LC_ADDRESS=C        
> LC_TELEPHONE=C       LC_MEASUREMENT=C     LC_IDENTIFICATION=C 
> 
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
> datasets  methods   base     
> 
> other attached packages:  [1] lattice_0.20-29  data.table_1.9.4
> lubridate_1.3.3  xts_0.9-7        zoo_1.7-11       rCharts_0.4.5   
> leaflet_1.0      shiny_0.11.1     RPostgreSQL_0.4  DBI_0.3.1       
> 
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] R6_2.0.1       
> RJSONIO_1.3-0   Rcpp_0.11.4     chron_2.3-45    digest_0.6.8   
> grid_3.1.2      htmltools_0.2.6 httpuv_1.3.2    memoise_0.2.1  
> mime_0.2        [11] plyr_1.8.1      reshape2_1.4.1  stringr_0.6.2  
> tools_3.1.2     whisker_0.3-2   xtable_1.7-4    yaml_2.1.13
```

i've updated all my packages...but it still doesn't work..

Packages are installed in the global library as :

```
DBI              "DBI"              "/usr/lib/R/library"           
KernSmooth       "KernSmooth"       "/usr/lib/R/library"           
MASS             "MASS"             "/usr/lib/R/library"           
Matrix           "Matrix"           "/usr/lib/R/library"           
RCurl            "RCurl"            "/usr/lib/R/library"           
RPostgreSQL      "RPostgreSQL"      "/usr/lib/R/library"           
base             "base"             "/usr/lib/R/library"           
bitops           "bitops"           "/usr/lib/R/library"           
boot             "boot"             "/usr/lib/R/library"           
class            "class"            "/usr/lib/R/library"           
cluster          "cluster"          "/usr/lib/R/library"           
codetools        "codetools"        "/usr/lib/R/library"           
compiler         "compiler"         "/usr/lib/R/library"           
data.table       "data.table"       "/usr/lib/R/library"           
datasets         "datasets"         "/usr/lib/R/library"           
devtools         "devtools"         "/usr/lib/R/library"           
expsmooth        "expsmooth"        "/usr/lib/R/library"           
fma              "fma"              "/usr/lib/R/library"           
foreign          "foreign"          "/usr/lib/R/library"           
fpp              "fpp"              "/usr/lib/R/library"           
grDevices        "grDevices"        "/usr/lib/R/library"           
graphics         "graphics"         "/usr/lib/R/library"           
grid             "grid"             "/usr/lib/R/library"           
httr             "httr"             "/usr/lib/R/library"           
lattice          "lattice"          "/usr/lib/R/library"           
leaflet          "leaflet"          "/usr/lib/R/library"           
lmtest           "lmtest"           "/usr/lib/R/library"           
lubridate        "lubridate"        "/usr/lib/R/library"           
methods          "methods"          "/usr/lib/R/library"           
mgcv             "mgcv"             "/usr/lib/R/library"           
nlme             "nlme"             "/usr/lib/R/library"           
nnet             "nnet"             "/usr/lib/R/library"           
parallel         "parallel"         "/usr/lib/R/library"           
plyr             "plyr"             "/usr/lib/R/library"           
rCharts          "rCharts"          "/usr/lib/R/library"           
rpart            "rpart"            "/usr/lib/R/library"           
spatial          "spatial"          "/usr/lib/R/library"           
splines          "splines"          "/usr/lib/R/library"           
stats            "stats"            "/usr/lib/R/library"           
stats4           "stats4"           "/usr/lib/R/library"           
stringr          "stringr"          "/usr/lib/R/library"           
survival         "survival"         "/usr/lib/R/library"           
tcltk            "tcltk"            "/usr/lib/R/library"           
tools            "tools"            "/usr/lib/R/library"           
utils            "utils"            "/usr/lib/R/library"           
whisker          "whisker"          "/usr/lib/R/library"           
xts              "xts"              "/usr/lib/R/library"           
yaml             "yaml"             "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: it's ok. I've tested with a lighter application using rCharts and it works. library has to be explicited in ui.r. In  local it doesn't need.

Comment: So, is the problem solved?